# How to save entry input to variable in tkinter i'm using python 3

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

How to save entry in entry variable my question is how to save entry into a variable?

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

```
user_name = Entry(frame, bd =5)
user_name.pack(side = RIGHT)
```

If a user types any data I want to save data in this variable like input:

```
user_name = input("Enter Your UserName!: ")
pg.typewrite(user_name, interval=0.2)
```

Now he is typing but when we changed into entry this script is not typing for example:

```
user_name = Entry(frame, bd =5)
user_name.pack(side = RIGHT)
pg.typewrite(user_name, interval=0.2)
```

Now he is not typing!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a tkinter variable like `StringVar` and set it as the `textvariable` of your `Entry` widget. Then you can access the content by calling the `get` method on the variable.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
user_name = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=var)
user_name.pack()
#var.trace("w",lambda *args: print (var.get()))
var.trace("w", lambda *args: pg.typewrite(var.get(), interval=0.2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Now What can i type here? pg.typewrite(user_name, interval=0.2) pg means pyautogui

Comment: Never used pyautogui. What is this line supposed to do?

Comment: I want to type text so that's why I used pyautogui now what can I type here

Comment: in chrome search bar

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Your question is asking _How to save entry input to variable_, and it can be done by creating a `StringVar` and access it by `get` method. If you are not really asking for this, make it clearer in your question.

Comment: @HamzaLachi I took a quick look at the docs of pyautogui. If I understand it correctly, you can associate it with the `trace` method of the `StringVar`. I have updated my answer on this.

Comment: no problem bro i found my answer you i replace with this pg.typewrite(user_name, interval=0.2)
from this:                                    pg.typewrite(var.get(), interval=0.2)